# regarding opencv loader in android

Tags: android, opencv

I am using async method to load opencv in my activity.

I wanted to know that I have to do it for every activity? Or it is enough to do it in main activity and then just do normal things in other activities?

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to do it in mainActivity. Follow the link below for details and more clarification:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Comment: I read that, but it doesn't say anything. Seems like I have to test it later.